# Alignment of images in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I want to create a PDF file that should contain a table and, under this table, three images; the images should have an horizontal layout (they should be on the same line).
How can I align the three images in MigraDoc? 
If I add the images in this way

```
   document.LastSection.AddImage("path1");
   document.LastSection.AddImage("path2");
   document.LastSection.AddImage("path2");
```

I obtain three images with a vertical layout under the table.
If I use

```
   document.LastSection.LastParagraph.AddImage("...");
```

instead of

```
   document.LastSection.AddImage("...")
```

I solve the problem but I introduce a new problem. 
The table that I've added using

```
  var table1 = new Table();
  .....
  document.LastSection.Add(table1);
```

appears under the three images.

What can I do to obtain the table and under the table the three images with horizontal layout?

Comment: Do you need to use migradoc or can you use itextsharp? just I know itext and can help with it but not with migradoc.

Comment: Migradoc, thank you anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `var para=document.LastSection.AddParagraph();` and then calling `para.AddImage(...);` to add the three images to one paragraph?

MigraDoc is dynamic - and `document.LastSection.LastParagraph` obviously returns the last paragraph before the table. To cure this, just add a paragraph after the table and add the images to this paragraph.